# How graph api get latest tagged friend in any post?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-friends

How can I get latest tagged friend post/comment/media whatever user tagged or friend of user tagged it. Is it about mention-tagging ?

FYI : The idea of app that I trying to do is get how many days since user and selected friend were in the same post/comment/media ?

Answer (score 0):

`/me/taggable_friends` is for tagging only, so you would only be allowed to use `/me/friends` - and that endpoint will only return friends who authorized your App too, so the App idea is not really possible when it comes to friends.

About getting the tagged photos, there is information and example code in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/photos/